# AngularJS-based UI Components, quantumui vs. angular-strap vs. angular-bootstrap-ui

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-strap

I have been looking for a component set for a start-up project which would be based on AngularJS.

After some research, I have found three common component sets which can be applicable.

**The first** is **[AngularJS Bootstrap UI](http://http//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**. It seems clear, but there are no enough examples and documentation.

**The second** is [angular-strap](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/tooltips). I have seen that it is a simple implementation of bootstrap.js with some additional features, but it seem very simple.

**And the last** one is **[QuantumUI](http://quantumui.org/)**. I have seen that it is amazing, but it seems very new.

What is the experience with these frameworks? Can you list pros cons for them?

Comment: This is really an opinion question, and probably doesn't belong here.  For me, the dependence on jQuery for both AngularStrap and QuantumUI make them both a no go for me.  UIBootstrap does have a bit of a learning curve for some directives, but overall it's pretty straightforward.

Comment: I'm pretty green in angular, but I got the impression that bootstrap-ui is maintained by the angular development team itself. Now I wonder, is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am owner of [**QuantumUI**](http://quantumui.org)  and is is not truth to say anything about other's projects.

However I can say that in short;

**ui-bootstrap**: is pure angular based, but it is old and not compatiable with new angular versions. Also it's plugins are very simple.

Also **angular-strap** is a implementation of bootstrap.js. Namely, it isn't a project of angular thinking.

However **QuantumUI** is a compact angular solution. It's components are powerful, server and developer friendly and also there is no Jquery dependency. All components are results of angular thinking.

Comment: Hi Mehmet. Why there are so few contributors on the QuantumUI's github page ? Your competitors have from 90 to 180 contributors.

Comment: Hi Andrea, I realy don't know :) There is no serious bid yet. However my competitors don't have quialified contributors too. If you look at thier activity, you will see the truth.

Comment: Hi Mehmed, first of all, let me say that QuantumUI looks pretty good. I wanted to ask, does QuantumUI works with AngularJS 1.4 and 1.5? And how about AngularJS 2.0 beta?

Comment: @MehmetOtkun can I use quantum UI together with ui-bootstrap (e.g. with Angular 1.5?)